# How to DRY up RSpec tests for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm learning RSpec and I can't help but notice there's a lot of duplication in my code. The following are just two examples of many others. Is there a way to create a shared test without having to go through every individual attribute?

```
  describe "validation" do
    describe "user_id" do
      it "should not be blank or nil" do
        @comment.user_id = nil
        @comment.should_not be_valid
        @comment.user_id = " "
        @comment.should_not be_valid
      end

      it "should an integer" do
        @comment.user_id = "a"
        @comment.should_not be_valid        
      end
    end

    describe "post_id" do
      it "should not be blank or nil" do
        @comment.post_id = nil
        @comment.should_not be_valid
        @comment.post_id = " "
        @comment.should_not be_valid
      end

      it "should an integer" do
        @comment.post_id = "a"
        @comment.should_not be_valid        
      end      
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first `describe` block you can set the subject to `@comment.user_id` like so:

```
describe "validation" do
  describe "user_id" do
    before { @comment = Comment.create } # or however you want to initialize your comment     
                                         # (FactoryGirl is commonly used)
    subject { @comment.user_id }

    it "should not be blank or nil" do
      before { @comment.user_id = nil }           #I edited this to make it clearer.
      it { should_not be_valid }

      before { @comment.user_id = " " }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end
    ...
```

This dries it up some and makes it a little more readable I think. Obviously you can pattern the rest off of what I have here.

---

EDIT: This doesn't save many characters (in fact you're typing more in the end), but it does eliminate the duplication of `@comment.{attrbute} = whatever` in the spec file itself. You can define a helper for each assignment, like follows:

```
/spec/helpers/comment_spec_helper.rb
def user_id nil
  @comment.user_id = nil
end

....
```

And do that for each attribute. Then in your spec:

```
    subject { @comment.user_id }

    it "should not be blank" do
      before { user_id nil }         
      it { should_not be_valid }

    it "should not be nil" do
     ...
```

The downside is, you'll have to do that for each attribute in the helper, and in the end you're doing a little more work. But if your primary concern is eliminating duplication in the spec file, this will help.

I don't know how idiomatic this is. I generally initiate new objects in the spec file for validation testing, (and my spec_helper normally handles multiple-step processes like clicking drop-downs, filling in text, then clicking "submit") but maybe you have more validations than I typically have.

---

UPDATE

I was working on a project and just flipped through notes from Codeschool's RSpec course that I took, and I thought I'd suggest shared examples. The example they give is:

```
describe Zombie do
  it_behaves_like ‘the undead’, Zombie.new
end

describe Vampire do
  it_behaves_like ‘the undead’, Vampire.new
end

shared_examples_for ‘the undead’ do |undead|
  it ‘does not have a pulse’ do
    undead.pulse.should == false
  end
end
```

This seems applicable, though you would have to keep in mind certain [conventions](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) to ensure your shared examples are loaded.

This would really DRY up your code, but I personally would be a little concerned about readability. I suppose if you use a descriptive-enough name for your shared examples you'll be fine.

Comment: An improvement, but not as much as I had hoped. I just `example_groups` but I'm not sure if they can be used in this context.

Comment: I just added a bit about `shared_examples` and then googled `example groups` only to find out that they're the same. D'oh! Anyway, I think they can certainly be used in the context.

Comment: Is this applicable for instance variables of an object? So let's say you want to make a `shared_examples` for `foreign_keys`, that should not be `nil` or `blank`, how would you pass the key dynamically to the shared example? The example you give passes an entire object: `Vampire.new`

Comment: Well, you can simply create in instance variable like I did in my first example and set it to the subject. So, for instance, `@vampire = create(:vampire)`, and then `subject { @vampire }`. I see you're asking for dynamic passing of variables, but I think this would be a bad idea. I think it should always be clear what the subject is for a group of tests, and using abstraction to pass in dynamic content would make it more difficult to ascertain the subject.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

It gives you a lot of simple matchers for your model

Answer (score 1):

You could use factories (e.g. FactoryGirl):

```
build(:comment, user_id: nil).should_not be_valid
```